# Is it possible to "directly use" header within itself to supress a warning?

Tags: c++, qt, clang, c++20, qt6

In all my code I use `pch_[project_name].h` file that includes every 3rd party header the lib/app will need and `ex` files of my libs in case of apps, e.g.:

```
#ifndef PCH_SFC_H
#define PCH_SFC_H

#include "sms/ex_sms.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

// ...

#endif // PCH_SFC_H
```

then I include it in every header file I create. `ex_[project_name].h` is one step further, I put there all the headers I created together with the `pch` file, and include it in every `cpp` file. Example:

```
#ifndef EX_SFC_H
#define EX_SFC_H

#include "pch_sfc.h"

class MainWindow;
class Projector;
class InFocusP132;
class IRControl;

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "projector.h"
#include "infocusp132.h"
#include "ircontrol.h"

#endif // EX_SFC_H
```

Now the problem. I'm getting warnings I haven't had before: "included header is not used directly". I dislike warnings a lot... so if I don't want to change my approach (and I don't), what's the least costly way to trick `clang` here? I want to keep the warning for other places (they are potentially informative), but I want them disabled just for these two kinds of files.

Sth I could put inside `pch` and `ex` files, not after I import them, I know how to do that. Is it possible or should I just live with it?

Comment: Have a look at: https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/include-cleaner (in particular: https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/include-cleaner#unused-include-warning and https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/include-cleaner#scenarios-and-solutions)

Comment: @ErdalKüçük "// IWYU pragma: keep" was what I was looking for, thanks!